# SSRS axis names independent of chart data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a chart that has two axes.  One is based on a range of dates and the other is a year to date.  My problem is that the person requesting the chart wants me to show the data for the year to date, and the selected dates but now would like me to show all of the available groups for the data whether they exist in the data or not.

For a little more clarity.  Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT     COUNT(AdDate) AS ErrorCountYTD, BusinessUnit, '' AS ErrorCountCur
FROM         MasterAnnotation
WHERE     (ActualAgencyError = 'Yes') AND (Client = @Client) AND (DATEPART(YY, AdDate) = DATEPART(YY, sysdatetime())) AND (BusinessUnit IS NOT NULL) AND 
                      (BusinessUnit <> '') AND (AnnotationDate = 'Final_Proof')
GROUP BY BusinessUnit
UNION ALL
SELECT     '' AS ErrorCount, BusinessUnit, COUNT(AdDate) AS ErrorCountCur
FROM         MasterAnnotation AS MasterAnnotation_1
WHERE     (ActualAgencyError = 'Yes') AND (Client = @Client) AND (AdDate IN (@ReleaseAD)) AND (BusinessUnit IS NOT NULL) AND (BusinessUnit <> '') AND 
                      (AnnotationDate = 'Final_Proof')
GROUP BY BusinessUnit
```

So if the client has 15 business units but their is no activity in 2014, I won't show any data.  Is there a way to write the first part of the query to have the business unit be independent of the data?  I have some business units that were in effect in 2013 but have not had any issues to report for 2014.

I am not sure if this is even possible in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, this is actually extremely easy to do in SQL.  I don't mean to offend, but it sounds like you may not have a lot of SQL experience.  If that's the case, I would strongly recommend reading up on some SQL basics, particularly JOIN statements.

To solve this problem, it sounds like you need to select one set of data that includes ALL of the businesses units, and a second set of data that contains the metrics for those business units.  Then, join the sets together using an outer join in order to persist the full list of business units whether or not they have a corresponding metric record.

One such example, that's incredibly lazy and probably not something you'd want in production:

```
SELECT
    ma1.BusinessUnit
    ,ma2.ErrorCountCur
    ,ma2.ErrorCountYTD
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    BusinessUnit
FROM
    MasterAnnotation
) ma1
LEFT JOIN
( 
    SELECT
        BusinessUnit 
        ,'' AS ErrorCountCur
        ,COUNT(AdDate) AS ErrorCountYTD
    FROM
        MasterAnnotation
    WHERE
        ActualAgencyError = 'Yes'
        AND Client = @Client
        AND DATEPART(YY, AdDate) = DATEPART(YY, sysdatetime()) 
        AND BusinessUnit IS NOT NULL
        AND BusinessUnit <> ''
        AND AnnotationDate = 'Final_Proof'
    GROUP BY
        BusinessUnit
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        BusinessUnit
        ,COUNT(AdDate) AS ErrorCountCur
        ,'' AS ErrorCountYTD
    FROM
        MasterAnnotation AS MasterAnnotation_1
    WHERE
        ActualAgencyError = 'Yes' 
        AND Client = @Client
        AND AdDate IN (@ReleaseAD)
        AND BusinessUnit IS NOT NULL
        AND BusinessUnit <> '' 
        AND (AnnotationDate = 'Final_Proof')
    GROUP BY 
        BusinessUnit
) ma2
ON
    ma1.BusinessUnit = ma2.BusinessUnit
```

Here, I put your original query into a "subquery", aliased as "ma2".  I created a new query of my own, where I only select distinct businessunit values (not often a good practice, especially if this table houses a lot of records).

By LEFT joining them together, I'll get ALL records from ma1 (my complete list of business units), and values for their ErrorCounts - if they have any.  If there are no corresponding records in ma2 for a given business, the ErrorCount fields will return as "null" values, which you can then deal with as needed (replace with zeros, leave nulls, etc).

You can tweak the WHERE clauses of each of the subqueries to filter down to the data you need.  The GROUP BY statements also probably don't need to be in the subqueries.  But really, the above query is just an example.